# Difference between "Putting in one's papers" and "Putting down one's papers"

Tags: idioms, subcontinental-english

I have come across these two phrases and both appear to mean almost the same.

As mentioned [here](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst15170_-to-put-in-one-s-papers-.aspx):

> *Putting in one's paper* means voluntary separation from employment.

and as I read [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20830/meaning-of-the-phrase-put-down-ones-papers):

> *Putting down one's papers* means resignation.

I heard both of these phrases are mostly used in India but what is the difference?

Comment: "Mostly"? Try "only". We should just say "I resigned", or "I quit", or "I'm finally outta here. So long, suckers!" like the rest of the world.

Comment: Btw, I'm Indian, and the first time I heard the expression was one of the only times in my life I didn't know what the other guy was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the difference is in the implication.

The way I see it.

Putting in one's papers implies that person is leaving their job but they are going to finish up the last of their duties and get things in order properly before they leave for good.

Putting down one's papers implies that they are leaving the job, possibly disgruntled, and getting out of there. Without bothering with what state they are leaving their workspace or projects in.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker of American English, I have never heard the phrase "putting down one's papers". The other, "putting in one's papers", means more or less as you said - to give notice of resignation.

Comment: Yes, As Mentioned It is mostly used in India and me too heard these phrases very recently.

Comment: Ditto: in the U.S., I hear "putting in one's papers" — perhaps mostly in the context of retiring from the military.